# Calculating duration of time using only Hours, Minutes and Seconds

Tags: datetime

How can I calculate duration of time between two fields using only HH MM SS?  I would need two fields that operator would plug in HH MM SS and have duration calculated into a third field in format that clearly indicates how long the operation took.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your two source fields datetime fields?

Comment: mast0r...Outstanding answer. It met the bill perfectly. Thanks so much! FYI, in order to ensure data integrity, I did add a validation rule for each Time field to ensure they did use the colon properly. Here was my formula for the rule, followed by the error message. Formula: **NOT( REGEX( Time1__c , "(((\\d{2}:){2}\\d{2}))"))** Error Message: **Time must include a colon (:) between each set of numbers. I.e. 11:11:11 for 11 hours, 11 minute, 11 seconds.** Thanks again...!

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible with a formula field. Create two text fields `Text1` and `Text2` where times are saved in form `11:30:00` (hour:minutes:seconds). Then create a new formula field of type `Number` with two decimal places:

```
((DATETIMEVALUE("2010-01-01 " + Time2__c) - DATETIMEVALUE("2010-01-01 " + Time1__c))*1440)
```

This formula uses these times and created two datetime values from it. And then just calculated the duration:

[image]

Comment: mast0r...Outstanding answer. It met the bill perfectly. Thanks so much! FYI, in order to ensure data integrity, I did add a validation rule for each Time field to ensure they did use the colon properly. Here was my formula for the rule, followed by the error message. Formula: **NOT( REGEX( Time1__c , "(((\\d{2}:){2}\\d{2}))"))** Error Message: **Time must include a colon (:) between each set of numbers. I.e. 11:11:11 for 11 hours, 11 minute, 11 seconds.** Thanks again...!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use DateTime?  If you go over 24 hours for an operation, wouldn't "13 days 3 hours" be easier to work with than "315 hours"?  Your formula field can do the math (difference) then format in whatever fashion you'd like to see...